# R: merge strings into one formula object

Tags: r

I have a character object that describes the control variables for a regression model. I fail to dynamically reference those correctly, whenever there is more than one control variable. Consider the following example:

```
x1 = runif(1000); x2 = runif(1000); x3 = runif(1000); e = runif(1000)
y = 2*x1+3*x2+x3+ e
df = data.frame(y, x1,x2,x3)

# define formula inputs
depvar =as.symbol("y")
variableofinterest = as.symbol("x1")
control1 = as.symbol('x2')
control2 = as.symbol('x2+x3')

# this works
eval(bquote(lm(.(depvar)~ .(variableofinterest) + .(control1) , data = df)))

# this does not
eval(bquote(lm(.(depvar)~ .(variableofinterest) + .(control2) , data = df)))
```

It does not work, since the dataframe obviously contains no variable `x2+x3`, but how can I disentangle those to reference correctly, when the input `control = x2+x3` is a given character (beyond my control)

Comment: `control2 = parse(text = 'x2+x3')[[1]]`

Comment: Do you want `x2 + x3` to be one single variable? I mean, the sum of this two variables must have just one coefficient.

Comment: If you want this, use what @Roland has said and use `eval(bquote(lm(.(depvar)~ .(variableofinterest) + I(.(control2)) , data = df)))` as well.

I attached you the solution as an answer, try, hope it works.

Comment: Why not just paste together the incoming text and use `as.formula` to convert?

Comment: I proposed `as.formula` option in my answer. @James

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can `quote` instead of `as.symbol`

```
control2 <- quote(x2 + x3)
eval(bquote(lm(.(depvar)~ .(variableofinterest) + .(control2) , data = df)))

#Call:
#lm(formula = y ~ x1 + (x2 + x3), data = df)

#Coefficients:
#(Intercept)           x1           x2           x3  
#      0.450        2.056        3.007        1.056
```

---

Note that when we do `as.symbol`, it adds a `backquote`

```
as.symbol('x2 + x3')
#`x2 + x3`
```

compare it with `quote` which returns a `language` object instead of `symbol`

```
quote(x2 + x3)
#x2 + x3
```

---

If it is already a string, then we can use `parse_expr` from `rlang`

```
control2 <- rlang::parse_expr('x2 + x3')
eval(bquote(lm(.(depvar)~ .(variableofinterest) + .(control2) , data = df)))
#Call:
#lm(formula = y ~ x1 + (x2 + x3), data = df)

#Coefficients:
#(Intercept)           x1           x2           x3  
#      0.450        2.056        3.007        1.056
```

Comment: thanks for the instructive answer, also regarding the different object types that `quote` and 'as.symbol' create!

Comment: Could your extend your answer as to why `dfff = filter(dff, x1>0.5)` works but `dfff = filter(dff, .(rlang::parse_expr("x1>0.5")))` does not? It appears to follow that both should work based on the argument in your answer...

Comment: @SAFEX  You need to evaluate with `!!` i.e. `head(mtcars) %>% filter(!!rlang::parse_expr('hp > 100'))`

Answer (score 1):

If your objective is to have just one coefficient for the `x2+x3`you should use `I` (Inhibit Interpretation/Conversion of Objects).

Futhermore, you would need what @Roland has said:
`control2 = parse(text = 'x2+x3')[[1]]`

`eval(bquote(lm(.(depvar)~ .(variableofinterest) + I(.(control2)) , data = df)))`

```
Call:
lm(formula = y ~ x1 + I(x2 + x3), data = df)

Coefficients:
(Intercept)           x1   I(x2 + x3)  
      0.4899       2.0157       2.0342
```

Otherwise, if you don't want to work with `eval`, `as.symbol`, `bquote` and `.(   )` you can use `as.formula` and `paste0`.

```
# define formula inputs
depvar = "y"
variableofinterest = "x1"
control1 = 'x2'
control2 = 'I(x2+x3)'

lm(as.formula(paste0(depvar,
                 "~",
                 paste0(c(variableofinterest, control2), collapse = "+"))),
   data = df)

Call:
lm(formula = as.formula(paste0(depvar, "~", paste0(c(variableofinterest, 
control2), collapse = "+"))), data = df)

Coefficients:
(Intercept)           x1   I(x2 + x3)  
     0.4899       2.0157       2.0342
```